# Unable to launch appium in real devices because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65"

Tags: appium, appium-ios, python-appium, appium-desktop

I am  trying to launch appium in real devices, but everytimee i run i get this error-
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.

It works fine when i run with Simulator, i have installed Webdriver agent in the specific path and have done all the necessary changes but still no luck

Following are the desiredCapability that i used in my app:

```
desired_caps['udid'] = '7d8dc98c8078f72de8b28fe3934664f70ebc97dc'
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS' 
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '12.1'
desired_caps['automationName'] = 'xcuitest' 
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Apple’s iPad'
desired_caps['browserName'] = 'Safari' 
desired_caps['xcodeOrgId'] = 'DWW94C2HRU'
desired_caps['newCommmandTimeout'] = '15000' 
desired_caps['xcodeSigningId'] = "iPhone Developer"  
driver = webdriver.Remote('localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps) 
driver.get("github.com/")
```

When i run this command- 
x**codebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=' test**  to verify if everything is working fine it got stuck here in command line-
2019-04-09 07:58:21.311906+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[489:69209] ServerURLHere->http://192.168.1.4:8100<-ServerURLHere
[Check the cmd line screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMKmN.png)

but i do see this according to appium tutorial- Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2017-01-23 15:49:12.585
    Test Suite 'WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest' started at 2017-01-23 15:49:12.586
    Test Suite 'UITestingUITests' started at 2017-01-23 15:49:12.587
    Test Case '-[UITestingUITests testRunner]' started.
        t =     0.00s     Start Test at 2017-01-23 15:49:12.588
        t =     0.00s     Set Up

Comment: Did you make sure you followed the tutorial in the link? Can you specify your environment?

Comment: Yes i did @Taegyung Device- Ipad(Version- 12.1) . Xcode version- 10.1. appium version- 1.11 , Mac OS- 10.13

Comment: Did you added **xcodeOrgId** and **xcodeSigningId** in your desired capability? Were you able to install WebDriverAgent in your real device by clicking **build and run** icon (play icon) from xcode?

Comment: @SubanDhyako
desired_caps['udid'] = '7d8dc98c8078f72de8b28fe3934664f70ebc97dc'
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '12.1'
desired_caps['automationName'] = 'xcuitest'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Apple’s iPad'
desired_caps['browserName'] = 'Safari'
desired_caps['xcodeOrgId'] = 'DWW94C2HRU'
desired_caps['newCommmandTimeout'] = '15000'
desired_caps['xcodeSigningId'] = "iPhone Developer" .                                   driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
driver.get("https://www.github.com/") . These are the cap.

Comment: These are the capabilities i gave

Comment: Additionaly to following tutorial you linked (which to be honest I think should suffice to make it work) you might check out this issue discussion https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/753
Remember that this error usually indicates problem with Signing/Certificate/Provisioning file/Keychain issues.

Comment: What happens when you build in Xcode?